# using os.path.join, but it's always doubling the '\' even putting it as rawstring

Tags: python, rawstring

Im trying to use os.path.join, to open some dataframes, but it always says the \ fold even putting rawstring.

when I create the "pattern_path" it works perfectly, and is only with a 
but from the moment I start using os.path.join it doubles the bars again, even if I concatenate the file in rawstring

```
import pandas as pd
import os
#importando os arquivos
caminho_padrao = r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Modulo 1\Python PowerBI'
vendas_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(caminho_padrao, r'Contoso - Vendas  - 2017.csv'), sep=';')
produtos_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(caminho_padrao, r'Contoso - Cadastro Produtos.csv'), sep=';')
lojas_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(caminho_padrao, r'Contoso - Lojas.csv'), sep=';')
clientes_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(caminho_padrao, r'Contoso - Clientes.csv'), sep=';')

#limpando apenas as colunas que queremos
clientes_df = clientes_df[['ID Cliente', 'E-mail']]
produtos_df = produtos_df[['ID Produto', 'Nome do Produto']]
lojas_df = lojas_df[['ID Loja', 'Nome da Loja']]

#mesclando e renomeando os dataframes
vendas_df = vendas_df.merge(produtos_df, on='ID Produto')
vendas_df = vendas_df.merge(lojas_df, on='ID Loja')
vendas_df = vendas_df.merge(clientes_df, on='ID Cliente').rename(columns={'E-mail': 'E-mail do Cliente'})
display(vendas_df)
```

and this is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [2], line 5
      3 #importando os arquivos
      4 caminho_padrao = r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Modulo 1\Python PowerBI'
----> 5 vendas_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(caminho_padrao, r'Contoso - Vendas  - 2017.csv'), sep=';')
      6 produtos_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(caminho_padrao, r'Contoso - Cadastro Produtos.csv'), sep=';')
      7 lojas_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(caminho_padrao, r'Contoso - Lojas.csv'), sep=';')

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:950, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    935 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    936     dialect,
    937     delimiter,
   (...)
    946     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    947 )
    948 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 950 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:605, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    602 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    604 # Create the parser.
--> 605 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    607 if chunksize or iterator:
    608     return parser

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1442, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
   1439     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
   1441 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
-> 1442 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1735, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1733     if "b" not in mode:
   1734         mode += "b"
-> 1735 self.handles = get_handle(
   1736     f,
   1737     mode,
   1738     encoding=self.options.get("encoding", None),
   1739     compression=self.options.get("compression", None),
   1740     memory_map=self.options.get("memory_map", False),
   1741     is_text=is_text,
   1742     errors=self.options.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
   1743     storage_options=self.options.get("storage_options", None),
   1744 )
   1745 assert self.handles is not None
   1746 f = self.handles.handle

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:856, in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    851 elif isinstance(handle, str):
    852     # Check whether the filename is to be opened in binary mode.
    853     # Binary mode does not support 'encoding' and 'newline'.
    854     if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    855         # Encoding
--> 856         handle = open(
    857             handle,
    858             ioargs.mode,
    859             encoding=ioargs.encoding,
    860             errors=errors,
    861             newline="",
    862         )
    863     else:
    864         # Binary mode
    865         handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Modulo 1\\Python PowerBI\\Contoso - Vendas  - 2017.csv'
```

Comment: The double back slash in the error message is not a problem. That is exactly how it should look when in terminal output. Check that path really exists

Comment: @Ftagliacarne What do you mean? Raw strings are exactly right if you want to embed literal backslashes without the need to escape them.